# Annotations disappear with setOption("useWorker", false)

Tags: annotations, editor, ace-editor

I am using the following code to set annotation in Ace Editor.

```
editor.getSession().setOption("useWorker", false);
editor.getSession().setAnnotations([{
              row: 1,
              column: 0,
              text: "Strange error",
              type: "error" // also warning and information
            }]);
```

This is displaying annotation on the gutter line number 2 which is good but if I press enter at the end of line number 2 the annotation disappears.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

editor.session.setOption("useWorker", false)

This turns of internal syntax checker (which uses the same annotations collections) thus preventing it from clearing your annotations.

I'm still looking for a better way without disabling syntax checker though.